# Event handling in react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and just started with event handling but while writing a simple onSubmit function I am getting the error (Cannot read property 'state' of undefined).

I know it can be corrected by

```
onSubmitFunct = event =>{}
```

but why doesn't

```
`onSubmitFunct (event) {}`
```

work?

I just invoked a function of a class app using `.this` then how is it `undefined`?

Why did I get `undefined` error when I am accessing the function of the same class using `.this` in the render function?

```
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDom from 'react-dom';


        class APP extends React.Component {

          state = { term: '' };

          onSubmitFunct(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.state.term);
          }

          render() {
            return (
              <div className="frm">
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitFunct}> //why this doen't work
                  <div className='infrm'>
                    <label>Enter Text </label>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.term} onChange={e =>
                      this.setState({ term: e.target.value })} />
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            );
          }

        }
        ReactDom.render(<APP />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 onSubmitFunct = (event) =>  {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.term);
  }
```

because in react this keyword is accessible by binding the  created function in constructor or by using arrow Function,and the arrow function is giving that feature by default in reactjs

Answer (score 0):

you need to add submit button for submit your form

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

class APP extends React.Component{

state={
        term : ''
      }

onSubmitFunct = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.term);
}
render(){
  return(
    <div className="frm">
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitFunct}> //why this doen't work
        <div className='infrm'>
        <label>Enter Text </label>
         <input type="text"
                value={this.state.term } 
                onChange={e => this.setState({term:e.target.value})} 
          />
           // add submit button for submitting form
           <button type="submit">
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to bind the method in constructor.

```
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
```

Your file should look like below.

```
class APP extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { term: '' };
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this); // Bind method like this...
      }

    onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.term);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="frm">
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className='infrm'>
                        <label>Enter Text
         <input type="text" value={this.state.term} onChange={e =>
                                this.setState({ term: e.target.value })} />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```